# MediaCodec multi-threaded reference

Tags: java, android, concurrency, android-mediacodec

There are two threads to access the same `MediaCodec` object, and they may need to run simultaneously. Now I have a problem: when the two threads are running at the same time, the code is following:

```
try {
   mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to deal with this code?

Because the two threads reference to the same mediaCodec object, one thread executes this code will affect the other thread's reference to the `mediaCodec`, and the other thread cannot run normally. How to solve it?

Comment: Just synchronize on the `mediaCodec` object? We don't know what you are trying to do to know further.

Comment: I'm trying to recorde the screen of an android phone,and push it to the PC while saving a MP4 file on the phone at the same time.I use a mediaCodec object to get stream, use one thread to save as a file and another thread to push it to PC.But when executes mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);they will affect each other.I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is wise access `MediaCodec` from multiple thread, you will need to be careful with the synchronization, and a lot of synchronization may stall your (encoding/decoding) process.

If you want to push it to the PC while saving a MP4 file, I think what you should do is do your `MediaCodec` stuff in one thread, put the output result in a thread safe queue and process the result in other thread asynchronously ( can be done by using Handler, Executor etc)

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not an must-have for MediaCodec to be multithreading-safe in synchronous mode (e.g. you can have a thread for `dequeueInputBuffer()`, filling one end of the pipeline, and a second Thread for `dequeueOutputBuffer()`, draining the other end of the Pipeline), I don't know of any HW decoder that crashes when you work with 2 Threads and 1 MediaCodec instance (and my App has been tested on a lot of devices). I think you are good to go.